# PHP PDO vs REGEXP Words boundary

Tags: php, regex, pdo

Uh I tried it like this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 
            `quotes`
            WHERE 
            MATCH(quote) AGAINST(:against IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND
            quote REGEXP '[[:<:]]:regexp[[:>:]]'
            LIMIT 1";
$exec = $result->execute([':against' => $word, ':regexp' => $word]);
```

It says:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens in

Then like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 
        `quotes`
        WHERE 
        MATCH(quote) AGAINST(:against IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND
        quote REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . PDODB::quote($word) . "[[:>:]]'
        LIMIT 1";

$exec = $result->execute([':against' => $word]);
```

But that makes (obviously incorrect sql)

```
'[[:<:]]'book'[[:>:]]'
```

(Should be like this, but sql injection safe)

```
'[[:<:]]book[[:>:]]'
```

How the heck should i do it? Doggo is bamboozled.

Comment: @user first case is that case of another parameter :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't quote placeholders. Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 
            `quotes`
            WHERE 
            MATCH(quote) AGAINST(:against IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND
            quote REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]', :regexp, '[[:>:]]')
            LIMIT 1";
$exec = $result->execute([':against' => $word, ':regexp' => $word]);
```

This way `:regexp` will be read as a second placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX word boundaries should be part of input string:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `quotes`
        WHERE  MATCH(quote) AGAINST(:against IN BOOLEAN MODE)
            AND quote REGEXP :regexp
        LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':against' => $word, ':regexp' => '[[:<:]]' . $word . '[[:>:]]']);
```

Comment: i selected user's answer because he was first but your answer is probably better. it is strange at first look but your solution is probably injection safe too. i think i saw it before like that somewhere but i was thinking it is unsafe and i couldn't recall it anyway.